# Sealed methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a slideshow that use Transition objects to transition slides:

```
function Transition(slide, settings){
    this.slide = slide;
    this.el = slide.el;
    this.settings = settings;
    this.duration = (this.settings['transitionSpeed'] / 1000) + 's';
    this.endAnimation = null;
}

Transition.prototype.inRight = function(callback){
    callback();
}

Transition.prototype.outRight = function(callback){
    callback();
}

Transition.prototype.inLeft = function(callback){
    callback();
}

Transition.prototype.outLeft = function(callback){
    callback();
}
```

Each of the methods correspond to how the slide should behave should it be transitioning in from the right, out to the right, in from the left, and out to the left. All well and good when the `Transition` is acting upon slides:

```
function ClassBasedTransition(slide, settings, transitionName){
    Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
    this.transitionName = transitionName;
}

ClassBasedTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition.prototype);
ClassBasedTransition.prototype.constructor = ClassBasedTransition;

ClassBasedTransition.prototype.inRight = function(callback){
    var self = this;
    this.endAnimation = function(){
        DomUtil.removeClass(this, 'nd-' + self.transitionName + '-in-right-transition');
        callback();
        this.removeEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', bound );
    }

    var bound = this.endAnimation;
    this.el.style.webkitAnimationDuration = this.duration;

    this.el.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', bound);
    DomUtil.addClass(this.el, 'nd-' + this.transitionName + '-in-right-transition');
}

 **SNIP**
```

However, as I have been introducing 3D transitions, I am actually transitioning on the gallery container, and not individual slides, it makes less sense to have four transitions, and instead to only have two:

```
 //3 DIMENSIONAL TRANSITION
function D3Transition(slide, settings, transitionName){
    Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
    this.transitionName = transitionName;

    this.galleryEl = slide.gallery.el;
    if(!DomUtil.hasClass(this.galleryEl, 'nd-' + transitionName + '-gallery'))
        DomUtil.addClass(this.galleryEl, 'nd-' + transitionName + '-gallery');
}

D3Transition.prototype = Object.create(Transition.prototype);
D3Transition.prototype.constructor = D3Transition;

D3Transition.prototype.inRight = function(callback){
     **APPLY 3D EFFECT FORWARD**
}

D3Transition.prototype.inLeft = function(callback){
        **EFFECT 3D EFFECT IN REVERSE**
    }

D3Transition.prototype.outLeft = function(callback){
     **NO OP**
}

D3Transition.prototype.outRight = function(callback){
        **NO OP**
    }
```

Is there some way to seal `D3Transition.prototype.outLeft`and `D3Transition.prototype.outRight` so that derived objects cannot implement them? I know we can seal objects in javascript, is there some way to seal individual prototype functions?

Comment: Just mention that in the API? Really, we're all responsible adults - tell developers to only override them if they must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a property not writable so it can't be modified by the inheriting class:

```
Object.defineProperty(D3Transition.prototype, 'outLeft', {
  value    : function(){},
  writable : false
});
```

Demo with two ways of doing it: http://jsbin.com/paqehera/1/edit

This solution prevents direct assignments to the `outLeft` property from having any effect both on the inheriting class prototype and on instances of either class. However, the solution is not perfect, because the property can be redefined on the prototype or instances using `Object.defineProperty` again (as mentioned in the comment by Benjamin Gruenbaum).

Comment: That's not his problem, the problem is that the inheriting object redeclares it and that takes precedence over the object's own copies.

Comment: If you check out the demo, you will see that the "redeclaring" is ignored.

Comment: In the demo - no, but I can certainly still do - `Object.defineProperty(Inheriting.prototype, 'foo', {...`. Not saying people will do that, but it's still an option

Answer (score 0):

The moment you make outLeft and outRight just functions

```
var outLeft = function() {};
```

Instead of prototypes, it turns into a 'private' method, meaning it can only be used inside D3Transition. You do however need to implememt it like this:

```
function d3Transition() {
    var outLeft = function() {};
}
```

Derived objects can't access the method, but it can be accessed from inside D3Transition, basically making it private.

I believe this is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the D3Transistion to have no outLeft and outRight you can set them to null or undefined as trying to call it will throw an error but it'll still show up in the properties list.

```
D3Transition.prototype.outLeft = D3Transition.prototype.outRight = null;
```

You're basically shadowing it by having the functions lower down the prototype chain so Transition.prototype.outLeft will not be used for instances of D3Transition or objects inheriting from it.

Comment: But I could still derive an object from `D3Transition` and create those functions on the derived type, no?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I see, you don't want that these properties to be shadowed. I don't think there is a way you can. In Object.definePorperty you can always do `d3instance.outLeft=functon...` or re define it down the prototype chain when inheriting.